# How to make Eclipse work with Gstreamer SDK?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, gstreamer

I try to develop an Android app using Gstreamer. I use Fedora 20 with installed Eclipse with ADT and NDT, Android SDK and NDK, gstreamer SDK for Android. But something goes wrong, when I try to build tutorials.

Everything is OK, when I build NDK samples (like hello-jni), but building is not complited working with samples from gstreamer SDK (definitely it is android-tutorial-1 from [gstreamer sdk installation]/share/gst-sdk/tutorials/). Here is what i see in log:

```
13:13:10 **** Auto Build of configuration Default for project Tutorial1 ****
/home/staslatgttt/work/android-ndk-r10c/ndk-build all 
GStreamer      : [GEN] => gst-build/gstreamer_android.c
GStreamer      : [COMPILE] => gst-build/gstreamer_android.c
GStreamer      : [LINK] => gst-build/libgstreamer_android.so
/home/staslatgttt/work/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/staslatgttt/work/gstreamer-sdk-android-arm-debug-2013.6//lib/libgstreamer-0.10.a(libgstparse_la-lex.priv_gst_parse_yy.o): in function priv_gst_parse_yylex:lex.priv_gst_parse_yy.c:1598: error: undefined reference to '__srget'
/home/staslatgttt/work/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/staslatgttt/work/gstreamer-sdk-android-arm-debug-2013.6//lib/libglib-2.0.a(libcharset_la-localcharset.o): in function _g_locale_get_charset_aliases:localcharset.c:158: error: undefined reference to '__srget'
/home/staslatgttt/work/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/staslatgttt/work/gstreamer-sdk-android-arm-debug-2013.6//lib/libglib-2.0.a(libcharset_la-localcharset.o): in function _g_locale_get_charset_aliases:localcharset.c:167: error: undefined reference to '__srget'
/home/staslatgttt/work/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/staslatgttt/work/gstreamer-sdk-android-arm-debug-2013.6//lib/libintl.a(localcharset.o): in function locale_charset:./localcharset.c:195: error: undefined reference to '__srget'
/home/staslatgttt/work/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/staslatgttt/work/gstreamer-sdk-android-arm-debug-2013.6//lib/libintl.a(log.o): in function __sputc:/home/slomo/Projects/android/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/include-fixed/stdio.h:376: error: undefined reference to '__swbuf'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [buildsharedlibrary] Error 1

13:13:11 Build Finished (took 972ms)
```

I tried to surf Internet, but I didn't find useful explanation how to solve this problem. All I understood is that problem is connected to Gold Linker. Only on this site http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+for+Android+development is a small tip about problems with Gold Linker on Windows, but I use Linux! Anyway, if I wanted to solve this problem on Windows, "this project" link mentioned there is not avaliable.

Can anyone help me with this? I don't know, what I do wrong, but I really need to solve this problem.

Comment: seems a lot of guys complain this when using ndk r10c. maybe need rebuilt all the prebuilt librarys. But the most quick solution is to use ndk r9 serial

Answer (score 0):

The NDK r10c wasn't support till 11-10-2014.

"The Android binaries are now built with the r10c NDK and as such binary compatible again with all NDK and Android releases" - http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/

Try it again with the latest NDK and GStreamer Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error... Google removed __srget starting from NDKr10c (check their official site in other fixed bugs). Downgrade to r10b or below and it should work.